# Why does "string.Contains" not work

Tags: c#

I am trying to find and replace the following string

```
<p><img width="560" height="207" src="~/media/1ECAC40BCE3C43CEA0FEDA423C1EF2D1.ashx" alt="Fifteen years of the NASDAQ" /></p>
<p><em>Source:&nbsp; Bloomberg, L.P.</em>&nbsp;</p>
```

Thus, I am trying to first find if the string contains "img"

and this is my code:

```
 // check for image width to change for mobile
                string gotit = "don't got it";
                string imgBody = Text.Render(Item, "Body");
                if (imgBody.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("<img width="))
                     gotit = "got it";
```

but it never changes gotit. 
What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Trying to apply string operations on HTML is never a good idea. Why don't you use a dedicated library for the task?

Comment: did you dump out imgbody's contents to see what got rendered? maybe it came out as `<img height=... width=...` instead.

Comment: When you step through the code, what is the value of imgBody right before the if statement?

Comment: I actually have tried to use Contains.("img") and Contains.("<img") ...

Comment: I have also tried to use imgBody.IndexOf("img"), nothing is working

Comment: Debugging tips/things to try (other than the obvious breakpointing): replace the `if` condition with `true` to see if you're observing `gotit` correctly. Copy the value of `imgBody` into a simpler project and see what `Contains` returns without any distractions. This will help you create the simplest possible example.

Comment: I have also tried using string[] words = imgBody.Split("=") ... words was null

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(imgBody)` to see what it really has...

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions ... I am sure I will find the answer

Comment: So are you sure that you're getting anything back from Text.Render? Maybe stop execution after that line and check what imgBody actually contains?

Comment: Are you sure string in your code and the string from the page being rendered are in the same codepage?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are able to get the contents of html correctly from some magical method `GetHTMLContents();`...

```
var input = GetHTMLContents();
var gotIt = input.Contains("<img"); //if present, it will be true else false and more importantly, 'gotIt' is boolean
Console.WriteLine(gotIt);
```

Further, the magical method `GetHTMLContents()` can look like this:

```
//using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://somesite.com/default.html");
}
```